# YAML Azure Devops: Step task reference is invalid. The task name is ambiguous

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am trying to use the AzureRmWebAppDeployment task to deploy WebJobs to an App Service (Azure App service deploy).

Here is the following YAML code (task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4):

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRm'
    azureSubscription: 'hidden'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'hidden'
    package: '$(Build.StagingDirectory)\WebJob'
```

When I try to run the build, it gives me this error:

```
Job DeployWebJobsCombo1: Step DeployWebJobsCombo1 task reference is invalid. The task name AzureRmWebAppDeployment is ambiguous. Specify one of the following identifiers to resolve the ambiguity: ae173df0-05de-4ac6-b5cc-853e9f951a33, 497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1
```

I've tried replacing the task name with either of those IDs(task: ae173df0-05de-4ac6-b5cc-853e9f951a33@4 and task: ae173df0-05de-4ac6-b5cc-853e9f951a33 have both been tried), but it says it isn't a valid name.

I've tried setting the name property of the task (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#task) but that doesn't accept GUIDs:

```
name: string  # identifier for this step (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore)
```

I haven't been able to find any information online on how to actually specify the identifiers ae173df0-05de-4ac6-b5cc-853e9f951a33 or 497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1. Can anyone point me to how to use these identifiers?

Comment: Apparently, there is also this particularly confusing variant: _Step  task reference is invalid. The task name contoso.cool-extension.foobar.Foobar is ambiguous. Specify one of the following identifiers to resolve the ambiguity: contoso.cool-extension.foobar.Foobar, contoso.cool-extension.foobar.Foobar_

Comment: "I've tried setting the name property of the task […]" Note that you've tried setting the `name` property of the _step_, not the task. They are distinctly different – a step _uses_ a task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So `497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1` appears to be the id of `AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4`

[Github for the task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV4/task.json) here.

It looks like that error can happen when two tasks\extensions exist in your Azure DevOps organization with the same name. See support forums [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/643633/yaml-deploy-task-error-the-task-name-replacetokens.html) and [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/288534/vsts-yaml-build-failure-the-task-name-nugetcommand.html).

I would expect that you should be able to use `- task: 497d490f-eea7-4f2b-ab94-48d9c1acdcb1@4` not sure why that is not working. I just tried and it recognized it as the `AzureRmWebAppDeployment` task. Maybe give that another try.

Also if you would like to see the tasks that exist in your organization you can use the API and hit this url to get the [YAML Schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/yamlschema/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

`https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/distributedtask/yamlschema?api-version=5.1` I would check here for possible duplicates.

Comment: The YAML autocorrect doesn't like it (in the Azure devops online editor), but it works when run. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Eric Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12772788/eric-smith) mentions the ability to check for duplicates in his answer.  You can [actually graphically check for duplicates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/marketplace/uninstall-disable-extensions?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) by going to `https://dev.azure.com/{YourOrg}/_settings/extensions`.  There you can find the offending duplicate task and removing it.  It was easier for me to remove the task that I no longer was using.  In my case I had an AWS S3 upload task that was duplicated.

Removing the duplicated/unused task reference fixed my problem.  I think this is a little cleaner than using the GUID of the DevOps task.

Comment: How did you remove the offending task?

Comment: Use the GUI as mentioned to find the dupe.