# Yaml Azure Devops TerraformInstaller is ambiguous

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform0.12+

Here i am trying to create aks using terraform, using azure-devops to deploy the resource to azure.
pipeline job has failed within a sec.
below is the pipeline code.

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: TerraformValidate
  jobs:
    - job: TerraformValidateJob
      continueOnError: false
      steps:
      - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
        displayName: Publish Artifacts
        inputs:
          targetPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/terraform-manifests'
          artifact: 'terraform-manifests-out'
          publishLocation: 'pipeline'
      - task: TerraformInstaller@0
        displayName: Terraform Install
        inputs:
          terraformVersion: 'latest'
      - task: TerraformCLI@0
        displayName: Terraform Init
        inputs:
          command: 'init'
          workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/terraform-manifests'
          backendType: 'azurerm'
          backendServiceArm: ''
          backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: ''
          backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: ''
          backendAzureRmContainerName: ''
          backendAzureRmKey: 'aks-base.tfstate'
          allowTelemetryCollection: false
      - task: TerraformCLI@0
        displayName: Terraform Validate
        inputs:
          command: 'validate'
          workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/terraform-manifests'
          allowTelemetryCollection: false
```

getting below error :
[image]

I have installed both the extensions:
[image]

Comment: The error message is telling you both the problem and the solution. What is your question?

Comment: @daniel : As per the error it is referring to the terraform extension, as i am new so not able to map extract problem ., Please help me to fix the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [YAML Azure Devops: Step task reference is invalid. The task name is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59996756/yaml-azure-devops-step-task-reference-is-invalid-the-task-name-is-ambiguous)

Comment: No , i am unable to understand, i am new to all these, kindly help with resolution

Comment: You have two extensions that provide different implementations of the task `TerraformInstaller`. It can't figure out which one to use. It's giving you the *full* name of the two tasks. Pick one and replace `TerraformInstaller` with it. Or uninstall one of the two extensions. Either will work.

Comment: Many thanks it worked, post uninstallation of one extension .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After installing these two extensions at the same time, I can reproduce the same issue.

[image]

The root cause of the issue is that terraform install task exists in both extensions at the same time.

[image]

Their simplified version of YAML task names are all `TerraformInstaller@0`.

To solve this issue, you can uninstall one of the two extensions.

Or you can  specify the full name.

For example:

```
- task: ms-devlabs.custom-terraform-tasks.custom-terraform-installer-task.TerraformInstaller@0
```

OR

```
- task: charleszipp.azure-pipelines-tasks-terraform.azure-pipelines-tasks-terraform-installer.TerraformInstaller@0
```